# Re-escrever e fechar array de um arquivo

Tags: php

Como faço para abrir um arquivo de configuração, re-escrever o valor de um array e fechar e salvar o arquivo? Exemplo: 
config.php

```
return Array {
    'DB_TYPE' => 'mysql',
    'DB_USER' => 'root'
}
```

config.php (Depois da execução da função):

```
return Array {
    'DB_TYPE' => 'pgsql',
    'DB_USER' => 'root'
}
```

**Note que DB_USER não foi afetada.** 
Poderia usar **fopen(), fwrite() e fclose()** para fazer isso, mas acabaria perdendo as outras arrays.

A framework fuelphp possui essa função (save()): http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/config.html

Não estou usando nenhuma framework .

Comment: Você quer persistir os dados? Terá que utilizar base de dados ou gravar as configurações em um ficheiro. É possível guardar os dados utilizando session (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.sessions.php), porém ao fechar o browser a sessão é destruída e o valor do array volta ao valor inicial.

Comment: o que eu entendi é que ele tem um comando que ao executar ele quer modificar o arquivo de configuração do bd e salvar o arquivo com um atributo diferente.

Comment: Isso mesmo @Skywalker

Comment: Não entendi ... explica melhor esse esquema de ler/gravar o arquivo que Skywalker comentou.

Comment: to sem tempo para bolar uma resposta, vou tentar explicar o que eu entendi, ele tem um arquivo de configuração, que dentro ta salvo esse código `return array (
    'DB_TYPE' => 'mysql');` em determinado momento ele quer modificar esse arquivo e alterar onde está `mysql` para `pgsql`
);

Comment: Este `return array (
    'DB_TYPE' => 'mysql'
);` me parece configuracao do de algum framework. Diga-me voce nao pode editar manualmente o arquivo de configuracao?

Comment: **Esta pergunta esta sendo discutida aqui:** http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4295/3635

Comment: Boa noite, ainda nao entendi se esta usando fuelphp ou nao, poderia ser mais claro? Voce quer trocar os valores destes arquivos de configuracoes, e um sistema que voce esta criando? Como este sistema funciona? Qual o seu objetivo exato?

Comment: Sim, é uma Classe que estou desenvolvendo; o objetivo dela é obter, setar e salvar o arquivo de configuração. Não estou usando o FuelPHP, só dei um exemplo de qual framework possui uma função parecida

Comment: Conseguiu uma resposta? o arquivo config possui a taga `<?php`?

Comment: Você inventou essa estrutura de array com chaves ? Porque array no PHP, existe de duas maneiras: `return array('chave'=>'valor')` e `return ['chave'=>'valor']` (versão 4.5 ou >)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou dividir a resposta em três partes: leitura do arquivo, modificação e escrita.

## Leitura

A função `require` normalmente inclui um arquivo para ser executada – mas se seu retorno é atribuído a uma variável, ele recebe o conteúdo retornado por esse arquivo.

Arquivo `array.php`:

```
return array(
    'DB_TYPE' => 'mysql',
    'DB_USER' => 'root'
);
```

Arquivo `index.php`:

```
$array = require('array.php');
```

## Modificação

Modificamos a chave desejada, como faríamos normalmente:

```
$array['DB_TYPE'] = 'pgsql';
```

## Escrita

Aqui escreveremos o arquivo de configuração novamente usando a função `var_export`, que exporta uma variável de uma maneira que possa ser entendida pelo PHP. Além disso, inserimos a tag de abertura e outros caracteres necessários para que não haja nenhum erro de sintaxe quando lermos o arquivo novamente.

```
file_put_contents(
    'array.php',
    '<?php' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 'return ' . var_export($array, true) . ';'
);
```

---

Então, no final das contas, o script ficaria assim:

```
<?php

$array = require('array.php');
$array['DB_TYPE'] = 'pgsql';

file_put_contents(
    'array.php',
    '<?php' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 'return ' . var_export($array, true) . ';'
);
```

Comment: +1 Dei a resposta, mas não tinha reparado que tínhamos feito a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 2):

Uma das formas para se fazer isso é:

Setando as configurações. Onde `$current_db_type` é a linha que você quer mudar no arquivo. E `$new_db_type` é a alteração que você quer fazer.

```
$current_db_type = "'DB_TYPE' => 'mysql'"; 
$new_db_type = "'DB_TYPE' => 'pgsql'";
```

Depois, instanciando o `SplFileObject` para abrir o arquivo como leitura

```
$file = new SplFileObject('config.php', 'r');
```

Em seguida, iniciando uma variável com o nome de **output** para montarmos o arquivo de configuração linha por linha, incluindo a linha alterada.

```
$output = '';
```

Em seguida, iremos percorrer as linhas do arquivo e se encontrarmos o **match** entre `$line` e `$current_db_type` - que é a linha que queremos alterar - ai alteraremos para os valores de `$new_db_type`.

```
foreach ($file as $line) {
  if (trim($file) == $current_db_type) {
      $line = $new_db_type.PHP_EOL;
  }
  $output .= $line;
}
```

Por último gravamos no arquivo as alterações

```
$file = new SplFileObject('config.php','w+');
$file->fwrite($output);
```

Notas:

1. Usei `Trim` para remover os espaços, pois eles fazem o **match** falhar.
2. Usei `PHP_EOL` para poder dar quebra de linha. `EOL` significa **End Of
   Line**.

Referências:
[SplFileObject](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.splfileobject.php),
[Foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php),
[Trim](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php),
[Constantes Pré-definidas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.constants.php)

Answer (score 0):

Essa função abaixo procura linha por linha a `string` que você quiser e dá um `replace`.

Você precisa de um formulário para fazer o `POST` também ?

### `INDEX.php`

```
<?php

    $arquivo = fopen('config.php','r+');
    $string = '';

    if ($arquivo) {
        while(true) {
            $linha = fgets($arquivo);
            if ($linha==null) break;

            # Busca na linha atual o que vai ser alterado
            if(preg_match("/mysql/", $linha)) {
                $string .= str_replace("mysql", "pgsql", $linha);
            }else{
                # Coloca tudo em uma nova string
                $string.= $linha;
            }
        }

        # Move o ponteiro para o início do arquivo
        rewind($arquivo);

        # Apaga tudo o que tem no arquivo
        ftruncate($arquivo, 0);

        # Reescreve o arquivo
        if (!fwrite($arquivo, $string)) 
            die('Não foi possível atualizar o arquivo.');

        echo 'Arquivo atualizado com sucesso';
        fclose($arquivo);
    }

?>
```

### `CONFIG.php`

```
<?php

    return [
        'DB_TYPE' => 'mysql',
        'DB_USER' => 'root'
    ]

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala amigo, é possível sim! Usando apenas algumas funções isso é simples.

```
    public function SetKeywords($Setkeyword, $Setvalue){
        if(gettype($this->words) != 'array'){
            $this->words = array();
        }
        $array = array($Setkeyword => $Setvalue);
        $this->words = array_merge($array,$this->words);
    }

    public function ReplaceKeywords($maskContent) {
        if($this->words){
            if(!$maskContent || strlen($maskContent) == 0)
                return $maskContent;

            foreach($this->words as $keyword=>$value)
            {
                $keyword = '{'.$keyword.'}';
                $maskContent = str_replace($keyword, $value, $maskContent);
            }
            return $maskContent;
        }
        else
        { 
        return false; 
        }
    }

    public function GetReplaceKeywordCount($maskContent){
            if(!$maskContent || strlen($maskContent) == 0)
                return $maskContent;
            $count = array();
            foreach($this->words as $keyword=>$value){
                $searchWord = '{'.$keyword.'}';
                $wordCount = substr_count($maskContent, $searchWord);
                if($wordCount > 0)
                    $count[$keyword] = $wordCount;
            }
            return $count;
    }
}

# instancia da classe
$string = new string;



# definindo o valor para cada variavel dentro
# neste exemplo a variavel {DB_TYPE} dentro do arquivo será
# alterada para MySQL
$string->SetKeywords('DB_TYPE', 'MySQL');
$string->SetKeywords('DB_USER', 'root');


# aqui você pode abrir o arquivo
# p.x:
#
# file_get_contents(filename)

$arrayConfig = "$configs = [
    'DB_TYPE' => '{DB_TYPE}',
    'DB_USER' => '{DB_USER}'
]";



# aqui a class string irá dar replace nas tag pelo valor definido na função SetKeywords
$string = $string->ReplaceKeywords($arrayConfig);

# aqui você poderá salvar o arquivo com fwrite()
echo $string; // return string
```

Em ação: http://codepad.org/2C8fP670

Esta classe você define o valor para variavel, abre o arquivo, pega o conteúdo e a classe irá percorrer a string, onde ela achar a variavel irá alterar para o valor que você definir.

Show!

Precisando da um toque, abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria da seguinte forma.

Suponha que eu tenha o seguinte código:

```
return array(
    'nome' => 'Wallace',
    'idade' => '25 anos'
);
```

Poderiamos pegar o valor desse arquivo e salvá-lo no mesmo script.

Para isso utilizaremos `include`, atribuindo o valor de retorno à variável.
Em seguida, alteramos o valor pela variável e salvamos o conteúdo dessa variável através da função `var_export`.

Veja:

```
$configfile = 'configuracao.php';

$config = include $configfile;

$config['nome'] = 'Wayne';

file_put_contents($configfile, '<?php ' . var_export($config, true));
```

O `var_export` vai exportar o valor da variável como um código PHP válido.
Note que usei `true` no segundo parâmetro, para que o  `var_export` não imprima, mas retorne os valores. Assim podemos salvá-los em um arquivo.

E o resultado do arquivo `configuracao.php` seria:

```
return array(
   'nome' => 'Wayne',
   'idade' => '25 anos'
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Realmente eu achei a pergunta um pouco confusa, mas vou iniciar, tenta o seguinte:

```
$array=array ('DB_TYPE' => 'mysql', 'PASS'=>'123', 'USER'=>'root');
```

*aqui muda-se o valor:*

```
$array['DB_TYPE']='pgsql';
echo $array ['DB_TYPE'];
```

Comment: Não é bem esse oque eu queria fazer, leia o comentário de @Skywalker